# ADB issues. Device is offline. Everything is up to date, Kill/start server not working

Tags: android

Trying to connect Unity with my phone, but first I want my phone to work in Android Studio.

Device is offline and all the topics with the answer "Kill-server, than start-server" doesn't work one bit.

anyone got something more on this?

Comment: Have you `Enabled developer options` under `Settings` and also enabled `USB Debugging`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your device in debug mode and then Restart the ADB.
After that run the project and you can see device is detected

Also try enabling USB Debugging in your phone